# Using WriteConsoleOutputCharacter and SetConsoleTextAttribute

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to write a program that will output via coordinates. I am using the windows.h include, and the function WriteConsoleOutputCharacter to print characters to the screen, however it ignores the color set by SetConsoleTextAttribute. Any ideas how to get it to output in color?

Code outputting to the console:

```
void Card::printFancy(COORD coord, bool top) const
{
    paint();
    LPDWORD written(0);
    for (int row(0); row < CARD_WIDTH; ++row)
    {
        coord.Y += 1;
        WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(Colorizer::getInstance().getCon(), _card[row], CARD_WIDTH, coord, written);
    }
    unpaint();
}
```

And paint basically calls a paint function in my Colorizer class with the appropriate color
Colorizer paint function (called by paint() and unpain():

```
void paint(uint color)
{
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(_con, color);
}
```

`_con` is the handle, set via `_con = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);`

Comment: A quick note: 
If I use `std::cout` between the `paint()` and `unpaint()` function it _does_ color the text, however using that method would make screen updates much more taxing, and the code more complex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the counterpart of WriteConsoleOutputAttribute().  One writes a character but doesn't change the attribute.  The other writes the attribute but doesn't change the character.

Use WriteConsole() instead.

Comment: Not as fancy, but it did the trick!
Use with `SetConsoleCursorPosition()`

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant)  in https://stackoverflow.com/a/9275247/15485 you may match `WriteConsoleOutputCharacter` with `WriteConsoleOutputAttribute`.

[image]

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void write_symbol_in_color(HANDLE h, SHORT x, SHORT y, const char* symbol, WORD color)
{
   COORD here;
   here.X = x;
   here.Y = y;

   WORD attribute = color;
   DWORD written;
   ::WriteConsoleOutputAttribute(h, &attribute, 1, here, &written);
   ::WriteConsoleOutputCharacterA(h, symbol, 1, here, &written);
}

int main()
{
   HANDLE hStdOut = ::GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
   if (hStdOut == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
   {
      printf("Invalid handle");
      return 1;
   }

   write_symbol_in_color(hStdOut, 0, 0, "R", FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
   write_symbol_in_color(hStdOut, 1, 0, "G", FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
   write_symbol_in_color(hStdOut, 2, 0, "B", FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
   write_symbol_in_color(hStdOut, 3, 0, "C", FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
   write_symbol_in_color(hStdOut, 4, 0, "M", FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
   write_symbol_in_color(hStdOut, 5, 0, "Y", FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);

   return 0;
}
```