# Could anyone give me an easy example of "WriteConsoleOutputAttribute"?

Tags: c

I tried to search it on the Internet but still don't get it. I have also searched the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/windows/console/writeconsoleoutputattribute) page about the function  but I can't read those terminology.

Comment: [How to use WriteConsoleOutputAttribute function correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587795/how-to-use-writeconsoleoutputattribute-function-correctly/31587985)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use WriteConsoleOutputAttribute function correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587795/how-to-use-writeconsoleoutputattribute-function-correctly)

Comment: @JeffHolt: (not the OP) I already looked at that one.  It doesn't seem especially helpful.

Comment: I typed `WriteConsoleOutputAttribute` in SO's site search and got plenty of examples.

Comment: @Lundin: Show us one, please.

Comment: https://www.tenouk.com/ModuleS1.html

Comment: OK, yeah.  That example and the others on the Internet are a bit of a mess.  I'm upvoting.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274745/using-writeconsoleoutputcharacter-and-setconsoletextattribute/46402696#46402696

Answer (score 1):

[Example and explanation](https://www.tenouk.com/ModuleS1.html)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;

int main()
{
    HANDLE hStdOut;
    LPTSTR lpszString = "Testing a character StRiNg";
    DWORD cWritten;
    BOOL fSuccess;
    COORD coord;
    WORD wColors[3];

    hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    if (hStdOut == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        printf("GetStdHandle() failed, error: %d.\n", GetLastError());
    else
        printf("GetStdHandle() is OK.\n");

    /* Get display screen's text row and column information. */
    if (GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hStdOut, &csbi) == 0)
        printf("GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo() failed, error: %d.\n", GetLastError());
    else
        printf("GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo() is OK.\n");

    /* Write a string of characters to a screen buffer. */
    coord.X = 10;           // start at tenth cell
    coord.Y = 10;           //   of tenth row     

    fSuccess = WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(
        hStdOut,             // screen buffer handle
        lpszString,          // pointer to source string
        lstrlen(lpszString),  // length of string
        coord,               // first cell to write to
        &cWritten);          // actual number written

    if (! fSuccess)
        printf("WriteConsoleOutputCharacter() failed.\n");
    else
        printf("WriteConsoleOutputCharacter() is OK.\n");

    /* Write a string of colors to a screen buffer. */
    wColors[0] = BACKGROUND_RED;
    wColors[1] =  BACKGROUND_GREEN;

    /* for white - BACKGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_GREEN | BACKGROUND_BLUE; */
    wColors[2] = BACKGROUND_BLUE;

    for (;fSuccess && coord.X < 50; coord.X += 3)
    {
        fSuccess = WriteConsoleOutputAttribute(
            hStdOut,         // screen buffer handle
            wColors,         // pointer to source string
            3,               // length of string
            coord,           // first cell to write to
            &cWritten);       // actual number written
    }

    if (! fSuccess)
        printf("WriteConsoleOutputAttribute() failed.\n");
    else
        printf("WriteConsoleOutputAttribute() is OK.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see an example, but not an explanation, unless you're asserting that the code *is* the explanation.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, The OP asked for an example. There are also links for further explanation.